# Control a View in a Fragment after Asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-view

I have a Fragment that loads data from web
So I'd like to make a RelativeLayout to show to user that data is still loading
When finished I want to make my RelativeLayout disappear

But here's the problem..
On my Xml of Fragment I put my RelativeLayout with my loading bar visible..
So my fragments goes throught this step:

1)onCreate() {inside this I have Asynctask.execute()
2)onCreateView() {And here I can manage my RelativeLayout with loadingbar through Inflater and View}
3)Asyntask.onPostExecute() {And here I want to make disappear my relativelayout..}

BUT in Asynctask there's no way to access to my relativelayout, and of course if I try app crashes because of NullPointerException [Obvious]

How can I manage this problem?

Comment: Can you post the related code?

Comment: I resolved.. Just declared global my relativelayout and everything goes right!

Comment: I got the same issue. Where did u declared it?

Comment: I uploaded my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems he did the following:

```
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.Layout.relativeLayoutId);
```

And use it later on in the class like

```
mRelativeLayout.doTheMagic();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but log returned this: `Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: Make sure you are on the Main Thread, you can only change UI on the Main Thread

Comment: Surely misunderstood. I thought I could change the contents of a view from another class, which does not have any view. Thanks. I need to improve my android skills...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the constructor of your [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to accept a reference to the View, then you can modify it during the [onPreExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) and [onPostExecute(Result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) methods. Why aren't you just using a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) instead? Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved:

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
     RelativeLayout mLoading_Bar;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Asynctask.execute();
     }
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View cView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            mLoading_Bar = (RelativeLayout) cView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_loadingdata_layout);
            return cView;
     }

     class ASynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

              protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
                    //do something
               }

              protected void onPostExecute(Void string) {
                    mLoading_Bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
     }
}
```

And that's all folks